# Running multiple nodeJS Applications

Tags: node.js, shell, npm

Is it possible to run for example 3 or more nodeJS Apps with a command via a shell script?

The idea is i have a shell script and navigate into app directories and type the `npm` command.

npm package `concurrently` is not an option.

```
#!/bin/sh

cd ./firstApp && npm start ...
cd ./seconndApp && npm run dev ...
cd ./thirdApp && npm run dev ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also have suggested `concurrently`, you didn't give a reason for not using that.

Another possible solution might be Lerna

https://github.com/lerna/lerna

> Lerna is a tool that optimizes the workflow around managing multi-package repositories with git and npm.
>
> Lerna can also reduce the time and space requirements for numerous copies of packages in development and build environments - normally a downside of dividing a project into many separate NPM packages.

One of things lerna can do is run all packages at the same time. Read the doco and decide if it fits your use case.

Comment: I don't give `concurrently` a reason, because i want to save time while starting more apps i need at one time.
Like docker, but not in every case i can use docker or i want use it.
I will have a look at lerna. it seems to be the same as `yarn packages`